# Where is the struct page in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I know that `struct page` is associated to a physical 4k page. But where are they? Under a 4GB environment, we need one million `struct page` to manage the whole physical memory. So we need several millions memory to store them.

From the expand function in buddy system, it seems that they are organized in to an array. So I think it does not share the space of real page. Am I right?

```
static inline void expand(struct zone *zone, struct page *page,
    int low, int high, struct free_area *area,
    int migratetype)
{
    unsigned long size = 1 << high;

    while (high > low) {
        area--;
        high--;
        size >>= 1;
        VM_BUG_ON(bad_range(zone, &page[size]));
        list_add(&page[size].lru, &area->free_list[migratetype]);
        area->nr_free++;
        set_page_order(&page[size], high);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a tree-like hierarhy. PFN in PTEs in PMDs in PGDs and so on: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html