# Where are struct page* initialized in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system

As we know, `struct page` in Linux, associated with a physical 4KB page and mapped to a pfn. This forms the backbone to memory allocation in Linux.
The `struct page` is described in `include\linux\mm_types.h` contains variety of information about the page. I want to know, when are `struct page` allocated during boot and who initialize these `struct page` structures and where (in linux)?

I was able to get some idea of where the pages are stored from this answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/63893944/13286624 but I'm unable to find how these structures are allocated and initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `mm_init`, called by `start_kernel()` in `/init/main.c/` and the corresponding `mem_init` in `/arch/x86/mm/init_64.c` :

```
void __init mem_init(void)
1286 {
1287     pci_iommu_alloc();
1288 
1289     /* clear_bss() already clear the empty_zero_page */
1290 
1291     /* this will put all memory onto the freelists */
1292     memblock_free_all();
1293     after_bootmem = 1;
1294     x86_init.hyper.init_after_bootmem();
1295 
1296     /*
1297      * Must be done after boot memory is put on freelist, because here we
1298      * might set fields in deferred struct pages that have not yet been
1299      * initialized, and memblock_free_all() initializes all the reserved
1300      * deferred pages for us.
1301      */
1302     register_page_bootmem_info();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [`include/linux/gfp.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/include/linux/gfp.h#L483) file. It has a bunch of `alloc_page` type functions. From there, using `cscope` or your favorite IDE, you can see every function that calls these functions and that will give you a sense of how the functions are used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not my doubt. When we use alloc_page*, we are just finding a free struct page (`get_page_from_freelist`), do some work on it and returning it.
I mean to ask, where are the `struct page` pointers first allocated/populated (which is probably during boot).

Comment: Yeah, I don't know the answer to that, but unless someone else knows, it may require what I suggested, using `cscope` to investigate who calls those alloc functions and seeing if you can track down which are the "boot" calls. Good luck

Comment: You could also ask on the Linux kernel mailing list. They would be way more knowledgeable about Linux kernel internels like this and more likely to give you the answer you're looking for. If you find out, post on here as an answer to help others (be sure to link the email interaction in your answer).